# Apache Camel route end when using try catch

Tags: apache-camel

I have a route which has a **"to" clause**. I have used a try catch block to redirect the exchange to the route if some exception takes place. The exception I had was related to max no of parallel connections allowed with the client. Seems, when the exception is resolved, every retry of the exchange was processed further where it was left. How shall I be able to end the route which had exception.

Following is my code.

```
from("direct:hourlyFeedParts")
    .routeId("appnexus hourly downloader")
    .doTry()
        .process(AppNexusProcessor.getDownloadProcessor())
        .process(AppNexusProcessor.getNamingProcessor())
        .id("Appnexus Feed Downloader")
        .log("Downloading file ${file:name}")
        .to("{{appnexus.partsDestination}}")
        .log("Downloaded file ${file:name} to local")
    .doCatch(Exception.class)
        .to("direct:hourlyFeedParts")
    .end()
    .bean(AppNexusProcessor.class, "updateIdempotentList")
    .choice()
        .when(simple("${property.CamelSplitComplete} == true"))
        .split(beanExpression(AppNexusProcessor.class, "getAggregatorProcessor"))
        .to("direct:S3PreProcessor")
        .endChoice()
    .end();
```

I was thinking may be using **endParent()** after

```
.doCatch(Exception.class)
.to("direct:hourlyFeedParts")
  .endParent()
```

Is this the right approach. I couldn't understand the exact use of **endParent()** from the documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add `stop()` in the end of the `doCatch()` block:

```
.doCatch(Exception.class)
    .to("direct:hourlyFeedParts")
    .stop()
.end()
```

Comment: Thanks. And shall that ".end()" be changed to "endDoTry()"?

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake. As I said, a catch block should be ended with .stop()

Comment: Yes, I got that. Used "stop".

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the redelivery mechanism, instead of reinjecting the exchange in the route?

```
onException(Exception.class)
    .maximumRedeliveries(2).redeliveryDelay(0);
```

You could split your route as well, if you don't want to replay the whole route or catch exceptions on only a part of your route: http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-retry-processing-a-message-from-a-certain-point-back-or-an-entire-route.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the route mentioned above is just a part of a big route. Re-delivery would retry all parts of the route which were successfully completed. That would be of no use. Moreover, there are several parts. Error handler is needed on all parts. The documentation you suggestion wouldn't help in my case.